# Check list for consecutive values within range (F#)

Tags: list, f#

In a sorted list of 10 numbers, I want to find out whether any 5 consecutive numbers are within a certain range. For reference: This is called finding a "stellium" (astronomical term, regarding positions of planets).

If the list is:

```
let iList = [15; 70; 72; 75; 80; 81; 120; 225; 250; 260]
```

I want a function

```
let hasStellium iStellSize iStellRange iList
```

that will return

> hasStellium 5 20 iList = true

The list is already sorted, so I could just proceed with clunky if-then statements (like "Check whether element 1 and 5 are less than 20 units apart, check whether element 2 and 6 satisfy the condition" etc.

```
let hasStellium iStellSize iStellRange iList=
        if 
             iList.[iStellSize-1] - iList.[0] < iStellRange ||
             iList.[iStellSize] - iList.[1] < iStellRange
        then true 
        else false
```

But there must be a more elegant way, that also allows for other stellium sizes without having to manually add if-then lines.

Thank you very much for your help!

(If the function could return the index number where the stellium starts, even better)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just combining two standard library functions:

```
let hasStellium iStellSize iStellRange iList =
    iList |> Seq.windowed iStellSize
    |> Seq.tryFindIndex (fun s -> (s.[iStellSize - 1] - s.[0] < iStellRange))
```

returns either `None` if no such range can be found, otherwise `Some x` where `x` - range beginning index.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. It returns an `int option` which is the start index of the range, or `None` if not found.

```
let tryFindStelliumIndex iStellSize iStellRange iList =
  let rec findRange i n = function
    | _ when (n + 1) = iStellSize -> Some (i - n)
    | prev::cur::tail when (cur - prev) < iStellRange -> findRange (i + 1) (n + 1) (cur::tail)
    | _::tail -> findRange (i + 1) 0 tail
    | _ -> None
  findRange 0 0 iList
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variant using Seq functions:

```
let hasStellium size range l = 
    Seq.zip l (l |> Seq.skip (size - 1)) 
 |> Seq.tryFindIndex (fun p -> snd p - fst p < range)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to hack in an "early return" with a mutable variable, but here is a rough version

```
let mutable found = false
for i = 0 to (iList |> List.length - iStellSize) do
    if iList.[i + iStellSize] - iList.[i] <= iStellRange then //Did you mean < or <=?
       found <- true
found
```